# Setting Cakephp sessions to database

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, session-variables

I just migrated my app from cakephp1.3 to cakephp2.0. I have problem configuring session to database.

I changed session configuration in core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database',
        'handler' => array(
        'model' => 'Session'
        )
));
```

I have a db table a **sessions**. Is there anything I missed. When I write sessions on login and redirects fine and I can read session variable fine. But on page refresh, the session is deleted.

Comment: @cryptic it is not resolved yet.. i am still working on it. I lose the session object when I refresh the page.

Comment: can you verify when you set the session values they are in fact being saved in the database?

Comment: I deleted all the stored sessions in the database and tried to login new records are created and session id is present. But when I refresh I lose info in session object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding, you are trying to use Cake's default database session handling, and you are not using a custom handler model, if so:

Set these configuration options for Cake to use the database sessions in `app/config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database'
));
```

Make sure you run this for the database you will be using to create the proper table, as Cake will store the sessions there:

```
CREATE TABLE cake_sessions (
  id varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  data text,
  expires int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I could not find a reference to this anywhere in the Cake 2.x cookbook.  I did find this https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/612 so it looks like this is on someone's radar now.  I was also able to see these fields in DatabaseSession.php, but I would have never figured out that 'data' has to be of type 'text' and not 'blob'.